# Vue.js Asp.NET core Form validation

Tags: validation, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs2

I am currently learning vuejs with asp .net core right now.
I am doing some form validation and adding some error messages.

The error messages are from the Server side here is my sample code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser([FromBody] UserModel user)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (_context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == user.UserName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Username is already in used");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            var userDto = new User
            {
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                Password = user.Password,
                UserName = user.UserName
            };
            _context.Users.Add(userDto);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Saving Error", string.Format("Error in saving user. \nDetails:\n {0}", e.Message));
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

And in the view:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="SaveUser()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userName">User Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Username" v-model="userName" required :disabled="isEditMode" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userName">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" v-model="firstName" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userName">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Lastname" v-model="lastName" required />
        </div>
        <div v-if="!isEditMode">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userName">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--TODO: Distribute to each control-->
        <div v-if="hasError">
            <ul v-for="error in errors">
                <li style="color: red;" v-for="detail in error">{{detail}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" @click="backToList()" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

Basically I am doing the validations from the server-side.
Currently the error messages are displayed below the controls
And I need to distribute all the error message inline with the inputs.
Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance.